# How to remove the symbolic path of a command

Tags: bash, path

I compiled and remove `rkhunter` into `/usr/local/bin/rkhunter`
After that I

```
yum install -y rkhunter
```

but when I try to launch rkhunter I need to `/usr/bin/rkhunter`
because it keep seeking for `/usr/local/bin/rkhunter`

I watched into `/etc/profile /etc/profile.d/` and `bash_profile`
and see nothing

except when i'm running

```
whereis rkhunter
```

I receive :

```
rkhunter: /usr/bin/rkhunter /etc/rkhunter.conf /usr/local/bin/rkhunter /usr/share/rkhunter /usr/share/man/man8/rkhunter.8.gz
```

so how I could remove this path ?
thk!

Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening due to remembered locations in `hash` table of current shell.

To overwrite existing entry of `rkhunter` use:

```
hash -p /usr/bin/rkhunter rkhunter
```

Or to delete remembered location of `rkhunter`:

```
hash -d rkhunter
```

To display current remembered location of `rkhunter` use:

```
hash -t rkhunter
```

**PS:** You can also exit the current shell and login again to get new hash entries.